# Using FQDN with MSMQ binding

Tags: wcf

I have one SOAP service which is consuming 2nd WCF service. WCF service is designed to use NET.MSMQ binding. 
Both SOAP service and WCF service are hosted on same server(172.16.26.59)
In the web.config of SOAP service I when I use hard coded IP or localhost then it is able to call NET.MSMQ WCF service successfuly.

Here I am using public Queue.

But if I use FQDN(MTRWebservices.NNYM.NNT) instead of IP or localhost then it doesn't work.

Can anyone please help , why my SOAP service is not able to resolve FQDN (MTRWebservices.NNYM.NNT) to its corresponding IP address.

It has entry in host file , I verified this by pinging MTRWebservices.NNYM.NNT , it return me correct IP (172.16.26.59).

In real time this FQDN will act as a load balancer based CPU utilization.

Comment: <endpoint address="net.msmq://172.16.26.59/MyPointOneWayServices.svc"> and  <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/MyPointOneWayServices.svc"> works fine but when I use FQDN     <endpoint address="net.msmq://MTRWebservices.NNYM.NNT/MyPointOneWayServices.svc">, it is not able to resolve FQDN

Comment: Please help as soon as possible